# MS Access -> Excel MsgBox appearing twice

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am writing an module in Access 2016 that opens an Excel spreadsheet, copies data into an Excel table, then runs a sub stored in the Excel file that displays a message box, then generates a graph (or at least, it should!).

This is the Access code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub QueryExportMod()

'variable initilizations and definitions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim totalFindingsQuery As String
Dim breakdownFindingsQuery As String
totalFindingsQuery = 'SQL text
breakdownFindingsQuery = 'SQL text

Dim tempQ1 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim tempQ2 As DAO.QueryDef
Set tempQ1 = db.CreateQueryDef("tempQ1", totalFindingsQuery)
Set tempQ2 = db.CreateQueryDef("tempQ2", breakdownFindingsQuery)

Dim rs1 As Recordset
Dim rs2 As Recordset
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("tempQ1")
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("tempQ2")

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\ExportExcelTest.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim table As ListObject
Set table = ws.ListObjects("Table1")



'Modifying files and data ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

ws.Range("A2") = "Total Findings"
ws.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs1
ws.Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs2

'Call autoGraph, the Excel sub
xlApp.Run "autoGraph()"

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tempQ1"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tempQ2"

End Sub

'to be able to run the sub from a macro
Function KGQueryExportCall()
Call QueryExportMod
End Function
```

And here is the Excel sub:

```
Sub autoGraph()

'AppActivate Application.Caption
MsgBox " <message> "

Dim tb1Range As Range
Set tb1Range = ActiveSheet.Range("Table1")

Range("Table1").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Table1")


End Sub
```

When I run the Access sub `QueryExportMod`, the message box is generated (another problem I have is that it is always behind other windows. Does anyone know how to force it to the current window, the one on top? I tried `AppActivate Application.Caption` but it broke my code), and when I press "OK" on the message box, the same exact message box will reappear. Once I press "OK" on this duplicate, then the Excel spreadsheet will open and everything else works fine. How can I get rid of this duplicate?

Thanks for your help

**EDIT:** I put added two DeBug lines in the Excel sub, like so:

```
DeBug.Print("1")
MsgBox " <message> "
DeBug.Print("2")
```

and ended up getting

`1
2
1
2` in the immediate window **when I ran the Access module**, so I know now that the Excel sub is being run twice, but I still cannot figure out what is causing it to do that. When I run the Excel module right from inside Excel, **I only get**

`1
2`

I believe it may have to do with the actual application opening twice? when I run without the message box lines, I see a stutter, like a window opens then closes almost immediately, then reopens again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add parentheses here:

`xlApp.Run "autoGraph()"`

In Access it just generates a runtime error when you add parentheses with `Application.Run`, in Excel it apparently runs it twice.

Remove them, and it will be fixed.

Comment: Wah. So extraneous parens aren't just superfluous, they're *actively harmful*! #TIL

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Erik! I removed the quotes and it works perfectly, thank you! I'm not sure what OLE automation is, how would you recommend I call a MsgBox instead?

Also, I have `xlApp.Visible = True` right after I copy in the data from Access and run the Excel sub. This has been working to bring up the actual spreadsheet. I put `xlApp.UserControl = True` both before and after the `xlApp.Run "autoGraph"`, but the issue still persists and does not seem to affect anything.

Comment: @J.Cal parentheses, not quotes. the quotes are *required*.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant! typo

Comment: If it works I think he got it right. I will remove the MsgBox part from my answer, I got that to work with another Access application once, but as said, bad plan. The harmful parentheses are because Application.Run actually adds its own parentheses, e.g. `Application.Run("MyFunction", "Arg1")` will run `MyFunction("Arg1")` and return its return value. Thus `Application.Run "autoGraph()"` should actually run `autoGraph()()` and apparently Excel thinks that's fine and just a double invocation operator or something

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that's good to know for the future! In regards to the message box, I realized a stupid error I made, I just moved `xlApp.Visible = True` up a few lines to before the `xlApp.Run "autoGraph"` line which solved it